# SQL JOIN ISSUE -which join needs to be used in this case

Tags: sql

I have tables:

Table 1:

```
CODE NAME
---------
 A    1
 B    2
 C    3
 A    1
 A    1
```

Table 2:

```
CODE NAME CODE1 NAME1   
-----------------------
 A    1    B     2
 B    2    C     3
 C    3    A     1
 A    1    A     1
 A    1    A     1
```

I want to match `table1.code` with `table2.code`, `table2.code1`. based on code matches I want to display Name from Table1 in table 2 fileds (NAME , NAME1) . Please help, how do I do this?

Comment: Perhaps you can show what you have trued so far, and also perhaps an example of the output you expect

Comment: alternatively, improve the question to show what is the expected result.

Comment: Please add a tag for the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT t1.NAME, t2.NAME1
FROM   table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON     t1.code = t2.code
AND    t1.Name = t2.Name  --if you need matching on table1's code change t2.Name to t2.Name1
WHERE  t1.code = t2.code1 --if you need matching on table1's code change t2.code to t1.code and
```

replace WHERE to AND

Comment: What's the issue? Can you paste output in your question as well?

Comment: WHERE CONDITION SHOULD BE LIKE THIS T1.CODE=T2.CODE AND T1.CODE=T2.CODE1 PLS ADVICE

Comment: ALSO, THE SAME WAY i DO HAVE CODE2 NAME2 AND CODE 3 NAME 3 FILEDS ARE THERE NEED TO MATCH TOO.

Comment: Updated and don't shout. Don't type when caps is on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at your `table2` as at two tables and `JOIN` them separately by different codes. For example:

```
select t1.code
, t1.name [t1_name]
, t2.name [t2_name]
, t3.name1 [t2_name1]
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.code = t2.code
left join table2 t3 on t1.code = t3.code1
```

Comment: Only two tables are there

Comment: facepalm. just try it. this query contains two tables (`table1` and `table2`) but `table2` joined two times with different aliases `t2` and `t3`